# Web API Controller not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've got a C# project using Web API. I've defined my prefix and routing for my controller, but I keep receiving an error when trying to access the "all" route:

```
{
"message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '.../api/InventoryOnHand/all'.",
"messageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'InventoryOnHand'."
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/inventoryonhand")]
public class InventoryOnHandController : ApiController
{
    public InventoryOnHandController(){}
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("all")]
    [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 50, MustRevalidate = true)]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllInventoryOnHand()
    {
       // Do stuff
    }
}
```

My WebApiConfig isn't the issue (I think) because we have other routes working just fine, can't figure out why this one is the odd man out. Our routing in WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**EDIT** Adding the WebApiConfig file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // require authenticated users in all controllers/action unless decoratd with "[AllowAnonymous]"
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());

        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new SerilogExceptionLogger());
        ConfigureJsonHandling(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }

    private static void ConfigureJsonHandling(JsonMediaTypeFormatter json)
    {
        //make our json camelCase and not include NULL or default values
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        json.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
        json.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;

    }
```

**EDIT** Adding the Startup file (shortened for brevity):

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        LoggingConfig.ConfigureLogger();

        HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();

        var container = IoC.Initialize();
        httpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapResolver(container);

        ConfigAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfiguration);


        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);


        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);

        Log.Logger.ForContext<Startup>().Information("======= Starting Owin Application ======");
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if it's a case sensitivity issue?

Comment: Just tried the variations **"inventoryonhandcontroller"** and **"inventoryonhandController"**, still unsuccessful.

Comment: Make sure the route behind the "api" part matches the virtual directory in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using attributes, you can't get routing by convention. In your WebApiConfig (where you have the route right now), you need to add a line to config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() like this:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

The call to the MapHttpAttributeRoutes extension method is what will pick up the attributes for the route/routeprefix and create a new route to your method.

Comment: Updated the code in my answer. You need to map the attribute routes first. Otherwise, the URL matches against your convention-based route, but convention-based routes can't see controllers decorated with the route attributes.

Comment: Done, still having the same problem though.

Answer (score 0):

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

The order in which routes are mapped is important.  Attribute route mapping `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` must be done before convention-based routes because when the framework is matching routes in the route table, the first match wins. If a route is match via convention then it will not reach the attribute routes.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //..other code removed for brevity

        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

ApiController

```
[RoutePrefix("api/inventoryonhand")]
public class InventoryOnHandController : ApiController {
    public InventoryOnHandController(){}

    //GET api/inventoryonhand
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 50, MustRevalidate = true)]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllInventoryOnHand() {
       // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Try this in the Startup.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    LoggingConfig.ConfigureLogger();

    HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    var container = IoC.Initialize();
    httpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapResolver(container);

    ConfigAuth(app);       

    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);        

    Log.Logger.ForContext<Startup>().Information("======= Starting Owin Application ======");
}
```

Comment: Re-did the ordering on WebApiConfig, added both configuration options in the startup file, and removed the "all" route. Unfortunately I still get the same error, the controller isn't being recognized. This happens when accessing **api/inventoryonhand**, as well as the previous **api/inventoryonhand/all**

Comment: And you say that all other controllers are working properly? Show the full url you are calling and the root url of the site.

Comment: Yes. The project is old and we can't speak with the original dev any more, but the code is similar to other routes defined. Just can't see why this one isn't working.

Comment: Show an example of one that is working. what version of web api is this project.

Comment: You say you added to startup. show what the start up looks like. Update the question with the changes you have made.